# Separated Schemes and Intersection

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a separated scheme. I am trying to show that if $U$ and $V$ are affine open sets then $U\cap V$ is also. I can see that $U\cap V$ is homeomorphic to $d(X)\cap (U\times V)$. Where $d$ is the diagonal map from $X$ to $X\times X$. Thus, $U\cap V$ is homeomorphic to a closed subset of $U\times V$. I do not see why "affineness" follows from this.

If $U=\text{spec}(A)$ and $ V = \text{spec}(B)$ then $U\times V$ is the spectrum of $A\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}B$. But how does this help in completing the proof?

Answer (score 2):

All closed subscheme of an affine scheme is affine. ($d :U\cap V \to U\times V$ is a closed embedding)

Comment: I am not (yet) familiar with this result and did not study subschemes yet, other than open subsets. Is it possible to prove my result without using this?

Comment: The definition of being separated has to be "the diagonal is a closed immersion", right?

Comment: It seems that you can't. You have to use the fact that the diagonal map is a closed inmersion, hence work with closed subsquemes

Comment: I am not sure if that can be proved without using this (I am not an expert in algebraic geometry so my comment might not be that meaningful) @NicolasBourbaki

Comment: Are both of your implying that $d$ is not just a homeomorphic map, but an isomorphism of schemes as well (which bothers me, since $d(X)$ is closed, how does one restrict the structure sheaf to a closed set?).

Comment: @Hoot My definition is that the diagonal is a closed map (topological sense)

Comment: @NicolasBourbaki : That closedness alone suffices to make it a a closed immersion (see Hartshorne  chapter 2)

Comment: @NicolasBourbaki Well, you don't—at least, not canonically. That's why it's a property of the morphism and not just the topological space of the image. Happily, the diagonal morphism is always a locally closed embedding (what Hartshorne calls an immersion, I think?) so it suffices to check closedness of the image. On the other hand I don't know how you do much interesting with separatedness without knowing what happens to the functions.